# About the projection on the unit sphere

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, banach-spaces, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert Space and let $A\subset H$ be a connected set such that any two elements of $A$ are linearly independent and also $A^{\bot}=\left\{0\right\}$ (this seems to be immaterial). Is there any known condition on $A$ which would imply that the map $A\ni x\to \frac{x}{\|x\|}$ is a homeomorphism onto its image (in either strong or weak topology)?

You can assume that $A$ with the induced strong or weak topology is locally compact and locally linearly connected if needed.

Moreover, you can assume that for any $r>0$ there is a unitary/isometry $T_{r}:H\to H$, such that $rT_{r}A_{1}=A_{r}$, where $A_{s}=\left\{x\in A, \|x\|=s\right\}$. This is a strong condition but I am not sure it helps.

Thank you.